# How to use pre-trained weight for training convolutional NN in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

In my experiment, I want to train convolutional NN (CNN) with cifar10 on imagenet, and I used `ResNet50`. Since cifar10 is 32x32x3 set of images while `ResNet50` uses 224x224x3. To do so, I need to resize input image in order to train CNN on `imagenet`. However, I came up following up attempt to train  simple `CNN` on imagenet:

**my current attempt**:

Please see [my whole implementation in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jshayiding/00fe32fa499ecbaab2554ac35e2a65f5):

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3))(base_model.output)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(256)(x)
x = Dense(10)(x)
x = Activation('softmax')(x)
outputs = x
model = models.Model(base_model.input, outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=50, epochs=3, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

but this attempt gave me `ResourceExhaustedError`; I occurred this error before and changing `batch_size` removed the error. But now even I changed `batch_size` as small as possible, and still end up with error. I am wondering the way of training CNN on imagenet on above may not be correct or something wrong in my attempt.

**update**:

I want to understand how about using pre-trained weights (i.e, ResNet50 on imagenet) to train convolutional NN; I am not sure how to get this done in tensorflow. Can anyone provide possible feasible approach to get this right? Thanks

Can anyone point me out what went wrong with my attempt? What would be correct way of training state-of-art `CNN` model with cifar10 on imagenet? Can anyone share possible thoughts or efficient way of doing this in tensorflow? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: ResNets trained for CIFAR10 do not use size 224x224, but just 32x32, for this you need to train the network from scratch, without using pre-trained weights.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I want to use pre-trained weights before using `Conv2D`. Can you share possible thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You  might be getting this error because you are trying to allocate the memory (RAM) to the whole data at once. For starters, you might be using `numpy` arrat to store the images, then those images are being converted to `tensors`. So you have 2X the memory already even before creating anything. On top of that, `resnet` is very heavy model so you are trying to pass the whole data at once. That is why the models work with `batches`. Try to create a generator by using `tf.data.Dataset` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) or use the very easy `keras.preprocessing.Image.ImageDataGenerator` class. It is very easy to use. You can save address of your image files in the `Datarame` column with another column representing the class and use `.flow_from_directory`. Or you can use `flow_from_directory` if you have your images saved in the directory.

[Checkout the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

Comment: I used 4 T4 GPU already, still not going through. Also I didn't try to allocate RAM to whole data. Please see [my attempt in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jshayiding/00fe32fa499ecbaab2554ac35e2a65f5) before making your answer. Thanks

Comment: It's not about the T4GPU.Try using ImageData Generator or create your own batch. You'll do good.

Comment: I don't follow. Can you make your attempt in gist based on my gist above? Thanks

Comment: Just import the `ImageDataGenerator`  Follow [this official tutorial](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

Comment: I know it is for data augmentation, but how do you sure that would fix the problem. Have you looked into my attempt yet?